# When subclassing UIView with a XIB file, why do I need to have a contentView property as a subview to display the XIB?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

So I have a subclass of UIView - let's call it CustomView - with a XIB file for the layout of its subviews.

In interface builder I set the Custom Class of the top level view to CustomView and made a class method to load the XIB and return that top-level view when I need to use it elsewhere in the app.

CustomView.m

```
+(instancetype)newCustomView
{
    CustomView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"CustomView" owner: nil options: nil] firstObject];

    ...

    return customView;    
}
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    CustomView *firstCustomView = [CustomView newCustomView];
    [self.view addSubview: firstCustomView]; 
}
```

This all works and I can access CustomView's outlets just fine, but it feels pretty hacky. Looking into the conventional way to initialise a UIView subclass with an associated XIB I found a single article using this same method, but the majority of tutorials use some variation of:

- Set the File's Owner to the UIView subclass. (Don't set a custom class for the top-level view)
- Add a contentView outlet to the class and set it to the top-level view in interface builder.
- Make a method to load the Nib and add the contentView as a subview of the class.
- Call this method in both initWithFrame: and initWithCoder:.

This works too, but I don't understand is why it's necessary to have a contentView property set to IB's top-level view as a subview. If CustomView is already a UIView why can't I just set itself to that top-level view? Wouldn't that be more straight forward? I feel like the more I try to understand it the less it makes sense.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the use of a "contentView" in XIBs follows the pattern of using a "contentView" in a ScrollView - some people find it easier to manage. Personally, I just add objects to the "main" or "top-level" view in the XIB. This might be worth a read if you want to know more: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8

Comment: Necro-bump, but isn't CustomView already as a content container for subviews here? I agree with OP that doing it the way majority of tutorials show, we end up with an extra UIView. The hierarchy looks like CustomView -> UIView (this is the content view) -> [subviews]. It should be CustomView -> [subviews]. But even I am not sure what is the proper way to achieve this and an extra UIView is hardly a problem, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯